# How to show that a certain number is not divisible by another in a proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am given the prompt:

> "Let $x$ and $y$ represent two integers such that their product $xy$ is divisible by 3. Then at least one of the two integers is divisible by 3."

I am to prove this using contraposition.

So far, I have, "If neither x nor y are divisible by 3, then their product xy is not divisible by 3."

My problem comes in when trying to prove this. I am not sure how I am supposed to say that a number is not divisible by 3 in a useful way that I can use in the proof. How can you show that x or y is not divisible by 3 so that I can show that their product is also not divisible by 3?

Comment: You'll probably want to use prime factorization.

Comment: Hint: fundamental theorem of arithmetic

Comment: This is an instance of [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma), and the standard proof is via Bezout's lemma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the division algorithm:

> **Division Algorithm** If $a$ and $b$ are integers, with $b\neq 0$, then there exist unique integers $q$ and $r$ such that $a=bq+r$ and $0\leq r\lt |b|$. The integer $q$ is called the *quotient* and $r$ is called the *remainder* of dividing $a$ by $b$.

As a corollary, $b$ divides $a$ if and only if the remainder is $0$.

So now, write
$$\begin{align*}
x &= 3q_1+r_1\\
y &= 3q_2+r_2
\end{align*}$$
with $0\leq r_1\lt 3$, $0\leq r_2\lt 3$. If you are assuming that neither $x$ nor $y$ are divisible by $3$, then in fact $r_1,r_2\in\{1,2\}$.

Now, for example, if $r_1=r_2=1$, then
$$\begin{align*}
xy &= (3q_1+1)(3q_2+1)\\
 &= 9q_1q_2+3q_1+3q_2+1\\
 &= 3(3q_1q_2+q_1+q_2)+1,\end{align*}$$
and so when we divide $xy$ by $3$ we get a quotient of $3q_1q_2+q_1+q_2$, and a remainder of $1$, so $xy$ is not divisible by $3$.

You should check the other two possibilities (one remainder equal to $1$ and the other to $2$; both equal to $2$; note that one of them will require a bit of care).

Comment: +1 for a proof which is not tantamount to assuming what we are to prove (or assuming an even more general statement). The OP is in effect being asked to prove that 3 is prime. So they may not assume that 3 is prime, let alone assume unique factorization, or Bézout's lemma,

Comment: Any information on what the downvote is for? While this is not necessarily the best way to do this, the OP said he was required to do it by contrapositive.

Answer (score 0):

Every integer has a unique prime factorization. If neither $x$ nor $y$ is divisible by $3$, then neither $x$ nor $y$ has $3$ as a prime factor. Hence, the product given by $xy$ will also fail to have $3$ as a prime factor. This of course implies that $xy$ is not divisible by $3$.